# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') in react

Tags: reactjs

Im new to react, i want to get input and store the input to the smartcontract. but i keep getting this error, can someone help me ?

this is the file (https://github.com/fahmifakhir/voting-dapp/blob/main/CreateVoting.js

Comment: document.getElementById("candidate + i") wrong interpolation should be "candidate"+i

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.